# SQL - Temporary variable inside SELECT

Tags: sql, variables, select

So I just found myself doing something like this:

```
SELECT
    Foo = 
    CASE
        WHEN a.Foo IS NULL THEN (SELECT x.Foo FROM x WHERE x.Id = a.Id)
        ELSE a.Foo
    END,
    Bar =
    CASE
        WHEN a.Bar IS NULL THEN (SELECT x.Bar FROM x WHERE x.Id = a.Id)
        ELSE a.Bar
    END,
    Alice = 
    CASE
        WHEN a.Alice IS NULL THEN (SELECT x.Alice FROM x WHERE x.Id = a.Id)
        ELSE a.Alice
    END
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.X = b.X
```

That doesn't look pretty. So I am wondering whether there is any way to create a temporary variable such as:

```
WITH Temp AS SELECT * FROM x WHERE x.Id = a.Id
```

inside the scope of `SELECT` and refer to it?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT 
       Foo   = COALESCE(a.Foo, x.Foo),
       Bar   = COALESCE(a.Foo, x.Foo),
       Alice = COALESCE(a.Alice, x.Alice)
  FROM a JOIN 
       b ON a.X = b.X LEFT JOIN
       x ON x.Id = a.Id
```

or

```
SELECT 
       COALESCE(a.Foo, x.Foo) Foo,
       COALESCE(a.Foo, x.Foo) Bar,
       COALESCE(a.Alice, x.Alice) Alice
  FROM a JOIN 
       b ON a.X = b.X LEFT JOIN
       x ON x.Id = a.Id
```

Comment: Is there any performance overhead with using JOIN instead of SELECTING only when necessary?

Comment: IMHO it depends on many factors (whether you have indexes, how large are tables etc.). But you can always take a look at execution plans and benchmark both versions of queries.

Answer (score 1):

how using join?

```
SELECT  COALESCE(a.Foo, x.Foo) Foo,
        COALESCE(a.Bar, x.Bar) Bar,
        COALESCE(a.Alice, x.Alice) Alice
FROM    a 
        INNER JOIN b ON a.X = b.X
        LEFT JOIN x ON a.ID = x.ID
```

Comment: Is there any performance overhead with using JOIN instead of SELECTING only when necessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN a.Foo IS NULL THEN x.Foo ELSE a.Foo End as Foo,
        CASE WHEN a.Bar IS NULL THEN x.Bar ELSE a.Bar End  as Bar,
        CASE WHEN a.Alice IS NULL THEN x.Alice ELSE a.Alice End as Alice
FROM    a 
        INNER JOIN b ON a.X = b.X
        INNER JOIN x ON a.ID = x.ID
```